# How to change mode from ListView outside of the ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

How can I change the mode from a `ListView`, outside of the `ListView`?
I know how to change it from inside (with `CommandName="Edit"` ect.) but not from outside.

With the DetailsView this is no problem `(DetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit)`) but how to do this with the `ListView`?

I search something like this:

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ListView.ChangeMode(ListViewMode.Insert);
}
```

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: are you calling the `ListView` class or are you calling the instance you made in the code?

Comment: I added the ListView in the ASP-Code.

I have EditIndex=0, but how to switch to Insert-Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
btnInsertMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
listview.Items.Clear();
listview.SelectedIndex = 0;
gridView.SelectedIndex = -1;
listview.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
}
btnUpdateMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
listview.EditIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define in the aspx code :

```
InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"  InsertMethod="ListView1_InsertItem"
```

And the listview will be in insert mode.

If you want to do this with a click on a linkButton :

```
protected void lnkMachines_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lview.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;           
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this in the button_click. listView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
But nothing happen.